# Manipulating data.table column recursively on other column condition

Tags: r, data.table, min

I need to calculate a formula in a data frame. Each set of values across few columns have to be, lets say simplicity sake, aggregated. However, I do not want calculation across rows. I want to calculate each set with another set based on condition else where.
This is what I mean:
I have a data.table.

```
data = data.table(A = c("a","c","b","b","a"), 
                  B = c(1:5), 
                  C = c(1:5)
                  )
setorder(data, by=A)

> data
   A B C
1: a 1 1
2: a 5 5
3: b 3 3
4: b 4 4
5: c 2 2
```

In column D I need to have and aggregate of values in B and C and values B and C when A  is "a". As I have more than one "a", multiple aggregations are needed. From every aggregate minimum should be written in.
Here is an example.
For row 1: (1+1)+(1+1)=4, (5+5)+(1+1)=12, so 4 is minimum - D1 =4.
For row 3: (3+3)+(1+1)=8, (3+3)+(5+5)=16, D3 = 8. And so on.
This is what I expect

```
> data_new
   A B C  D
1: a 1 1  4
2: a 5 5 12
3: b 3 3  8
4: b 4 4 10
5: c 2 2  6
```

I tried this and run into issues.

```
for (i in data)data[i, D:=(min((data[i,B+C]) + (data[a=="a",(B+C)])))]
```

The expression below for minimum selection works fine on its own when I substitute i for a row number returning list of two numbers for min() returns proper value. Below answer is 8.

```
min((data[3,B+C]) + (data[A=="a",(B+C)]))
```

My previous attempts involved grid.expansion() and intersection(). However, with the size of my data set I ran into memory issue and Rstudio quit on me. As a side note, I need to run the calculations as I could not project the smallest outcome by "a" beforehand - it is a set of coordinates and they do not correlate with the magnitude of an answer.

Any suggestion where is my glaring issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value of `B + C` where `A = 'a'` in a variable (`val`). For each row you can take minimum of `B + C + val` value.

```
library(data.table)

val <- data[A =='a', B + C]
data[, D := min(B + C + val), seq_len(nrow(data))]
data

#   A B C  D
#1: a 1 1  4
#2: a 5 5 12
#3: b 3 3  8
#4: b 4 4 10
#5: c 2 2  6
```

---

You can also use `lapply` :

```
data[, D := lapply(B + C, function(x) min(x + val))]
```

Comment: Thank you your answer was an awesome guide. My question was quite a simplification of the problem to my own detriment. However, that was what I needed to get on the write path. I am calculating distances hence minimum upfront was not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to replicate the 'a' rows after taking the `min` of 'B', 'C' and then do a direct `+` with the 'B', 'C' columns.  The advantage is that, we don't have to group or loop

```
library(data.table)
Reduce(`+`, (data[A == 'a', .(B = min(B), C = min(C))][rep(seq_len(.N), nrow(data))] + data[, .(B, C)]))
#[1]  4 12  8 10  6
```

---

Or in a single line

```
data[, D := B + C + min(B[A== 'a']) + min(C[A== 'a'])]
data$D
#[1]  4 12  8 10  6
```